# I can't install Tor (unexpectedly exited)

Tags: tor-install

It is the first time I try to install it, and I get this error and I don't have any log by copying to clipboard, I use Windows and I've already restarted everything... version 6.0.8
Thanks
[image]

Comment: Can you check your antivirus and windows application event logs for any related entries?

Comment: nothing appear...